# c# adding xml element where attribute equals

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sqlite, parsing

I have an xml file that has a bunch of channels, and I want to append a channel category to every single one of them. Depending on what channel it is. I'm very new to this so please excuse me if this is an obvious error.

example:

```
<channel-category>Entertainment</channel-category>
```

or

```
<channel-category>News</channel-category>
```

I have tried the following:

```
        string path;
        string xmlfile = "/channels.xml";
        path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + xmlfile;

        if (exists("channelname1"))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("list/channel[@id='channelname1'");
            XmlNode category = doc.CreateElement("channel-category");
            category.InnerText = "channelcataegorygoeshere";
            node.AppendChild(category);
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not found");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static bool exists(string channelname)
    {
        string path;
        string xmlfile = "/channels.xml";
        path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + xmlfile;
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

        bool doesexists = (from data in xmlDoc.Element("list").Elements("channel")
                       where (string)data.Attribute("id") == channelname
                       select data).Any();
        return doesexists;
    }
```

but it's giving me the following error and I can't figure it out.. What am I doing wrong?

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
    Additional information: 'list/channel[@id='channelname1'' has an invalid token.
```

from this line

```
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("list/channel[@id='channelname1'");
```

My XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list info="list">
  <channel id="channelname1">
    <display-name lang="en">channelname1</display-name>
    <icon src="http://locationtologo.com/" />
    <url>http://someurl.com</url>
  </channel>
  <channel id="channelname2">
    <display-name lang="en">channelname2</display-name>
    <icon src="http://locationtologo.com/" />
    <url>http://someurl.com</url>
  </channel>
  <channel id="channelname3">
    <display-name lang="en">channelname3</display-name>
    <icon src="http://locationtologo.com/" />
    <url>http://someurl.com</url>
  </channel>
  <channel id="channelname4">
    <display-name lang="en">channelname4</display-name>
    <icon src="http://locationtologo.com/" />
    <url>http://someurl.com</url>
  </channel>
</list>
```

Comment: `from data in xmlDoc.Element("tv")` - your xml do not have `tv` element.

Comment: sorry, I pasted the wrong error.

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: 'list/channel[@id='channelname1'' has an invalid token.`

from this line:
`XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("list/channel[@id='channelname1'");`

I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have **closing bracket** in `list/channel[@id='channelname1'(HERE)`.

Moreover, you are actually trying to do following:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\channels.xml");
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("list/channel[@id=\"channelname1\"]");
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        var el = doc.CreateElement("channel-category");
        el.InnerText = "SomeValue";
        node.AppendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh I see... I was doing it completely wrong.. I've tried what you have said and while it's not giving any errors it's not actually saving the new appended element to the xml file. I have stepped through it and can see it appends it but when I go into the xml file nothing was changed. any thoughts?

Comment: ignore that previous comment.. I forgot doc.save. It works!! thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using tv instead of list thats why xml library not getting your path of your elements  and throwing this error.

try this..

```
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("list/channel");
node.Attributes["id"].Value=="channelname1"?true:false;
```

Comment: sorry, I pasted the wrong error.

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: 'list/channel[@id='channelname1'' has an invalid token.`

from this line:
`XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("list/channel[@id='channelname1'");`

I have edited my post.

Comment: @RangaSarin try this edited one you can further put this in a loop

Comment: I got it working using Paweł Dyl's method. Thank you so much for all your time and help though it's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool doesexists = (from data in xmlDoc.Element("tv").Elements("channel")
                   where (string)data.Attribute("id") == channelname
                   select data).Any();
```

You are trying to reach the `channel` node where the `id` equals the channelname inside `tv`. The problem is that `tv` does not exist, the channels are inside this:

```
<list info="list">
```

Solution: either put the channels into `tv`, or use a selector appropriate to your current structure.

Comment: sorry, it was a paste error. I have updated my original post with the correct error and code. even using list still throws same error.